# wordpress firstpost for category

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

Hi im trying to get the first post from category 5 and make two diffrent classes. But all my posts gets the class "regular", i want the first post (only the first post) to have the class "featured" and the rest of them the class "regular" cant figure out whats wrong. HALP! :)
Oh btw the code works if i remove the first line of the code, but then it gets all posts from all categories :/

```
   <?php query_posts('cat=5');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if (is_paged()) : $postclass = ('regular'); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php $postclass = ($post == $posts[0]) ? 'featured' : 'regular'; ?>
    <?php echo $postclass; ?>   
   <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try setting `$postclass` to "featured" outside your loop, and once it's been displayed, set it to "regular"?

Making a small change to your code without changing the logic:

```
<?php 
query_posts('cat=5');
$postclass = 'featured';
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    if (is_paged()) : 
        $postclass = 'regular';
    else :
        echo $postclass;
        $postclass = 'regular';
    endif;
endwhile
?>
```

Or if that doesn't make sense to you, how about using a boolean?

```
<?php 
query_posts('cat=5');
$first = true;
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    if (is_paged()) : 
        $postclass = 'regular';
    else :
        $postclass = $first ? 'featured' : 'regular';
        echo $postclass;
        $first = false;
    endif;
endwhile
?>
```